# How to delete unsaved changes in Paw app?

Tags: paw-app

I have a long list of unsaved changes in my branches dropdown. It's hard to filter through my actual saved snapshots and I was wondering how to delete unsaved changes and/or snapshots to clear up this list.

Answer (score 0):

If *unsaved* changes mean **snapshots**, the answer is no as at the time of writing this answer. There is no way to delete/clear unwanted snapshots. I hope that they will consider adding support for this in future.